# How to automate Maven and Java JDK8 installation with groovy for Jenkins?

Tags: java, maven, docker, jenkins, groovy

I'm building a Jenkins Docker image and I will like to automate the installation of Maven 3 and Java 8 last JDK. But unfortunately I use these two groovy files locate into the groovy folder:

**groovy/java.groovy**:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.tools.*

def inst = Jenkins.getInstance()

def desc = inst.getDescriptor("hudson.model.JDK")

def versions = [ "jdk8": "jdk-8u202"]
def installations = [];

for (v in versions) {
  def installer = new JDKInstaller(v.value, true)
  def installerProps = new InstallSourceProperty([installer])
  def installation = new JDK(v.key, "", [installerProps])
  installations.push(installation)
}

desc.setInstallations(installations.toArray(new JDK[0]))

desc.save()
```

**groovy/maven.groovy**:

```
import jenkins.*;
import jenkins.model.*;
import hudson.*;
import hudson.model.*;

mavenName = "maven3"
mavenVersion = "3.6.0"
println("Checking Maven installations...")

// Grab the Maven "task" (which is the plugin handle).
mavenPlugin = Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList(hudson.tasks.Maven.DescriptorImpl.class)[0]

// Check for a matching installation.
maven3Install = mavenPlugin.installations.find {
   install -> install.name.equals(mavenName)
}

// If no match was found, add an installation.
if(maven3Install == null) {
   println("No Maven install found. Adding...")

   newMavenInstall = new hudson.tasks.Maven.MavenInstallation('maven3', null,
    [new hudson.tools.InstallSourceProperty([new hudson.tasks.Maven.MavenInstaller(mavenVersion)])]
)

   mavenPlugin.installations += newMavenInstall
   mavenPlugin.save()

   println("Maven install added.")
} else {
   println("Maven install found. Done.")
}
```

and then I run the command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v `pwd`/groovy:/var/jenkins_home/jobs --rm --name jenkinsdocker jenkinsdocker:latest
```

Unfortunately this returns an error:

```
java.io.IOException: jenkins.model.InvalidBuildsDir: ${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds does not exist and probably cannot be created
```

I'm just wondering if the groovy files are wrong or if there is something else I missed?

How can I automate the maven/java installation for Jenkins while running a **docker run**? Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: `jenkinsdocker` image is not present in Docker Hub, so I am assuming is a local image that you have created. Could you provide more deatils about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find jenkinsdocker image, so I guess is some docker image you generated from jenkins. In any case following [this jenkinsdocker documentation](https://cinqict.github.io/post/eric/jenkinsdocker/) you should put your groovy scripts in the `init.groovy.d` folder to be executed on init. So you need to run docker modifying `jobs` by `init.groovy.d` and use the `jenkins:latest` image:

```
     docker run -p 8080:8080 -v `pwd`/groovy:/var/jenkins_home/init.groovy.d/ --rm --name jenkins jenkins:latest
```

You can also create your own Dockerfile (you can use version 2.60.3 for instance) as in the example above:

```
# Extended from https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.60.3

# Skip setup wizard
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"

# Add groovy script to Jenkins hook
COPY --chown=jenkins:jenkins groovy/ /var/jenkins_home/init.groovy.d/
```

Build and run the container:

```
docker build jenkinsdocker -t .
docker run -p 8080:8080 --name jenkinsdocker jenkinsdocker:latest
```

Comment: Doesnt match my case but i will accept it as answer as a workaround. Thx